# Why is Indy not retrieving some of my mailbodies

Tags: delphi, email, indy, pop3

I have the following code I use for retrieving mails from a POP3 account.
It is working very well most of the time, but from time to time there are some mails where it doesn't retrieve the body.
If I test the IdMessage.MessageParts.Count it says that it is 0 - if I use another mailclient to retrieve the mail there is no problem.
I have a TIdPOP3 and a TIdMessage component on the form.
The connection is OK as there may be some mails that are show OK.

I can't figure out any system in which mails are not shown correct and which are not. But there might be one.
I use Delphi XE3 and the Indy is version 10.5.9.0

```
procedure TfrmJsMailCollect.lstMailsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MailBody: string;
  intIndex: integer;
begin
  if (lstMails.Items.Count = 0) or (lstMails.SelCount = 0) then
    Exit;
  MailBody := '';
  try
    begin
      mmoBody.Clear;
      lstMails.Selected.SubItems.Strings[0];
      lstMails.Selected.ImageIndex := 4;
      conPOP3.Retrieve(lstMails.Selected.Index + 1, IdMessage);

      for intIndex := 0 To Pred(IdMessage.MessageParts.Count) do
        begin
          if (IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[intIndex] is TIdAttachmentFile) then
            begin // Attachments are skipped
            end
          else
            begin // body text
              if Pos('text/plain', IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[intIndex].ContentType) <> 0 then
                begin
                  if TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[intIndex]).Body.Text <> '' then
                    begin
                      MailBody := MailBody + TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[intIndex]).Body.Text;
                      mmoBody.Lines.Add(MailBody);
                      MemoValidate;
                    end;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
    mmoBody.CaretPos.SetLocation(0, 0);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  except
    Logfile.Error('F_JsMailCollect.lstMailsClick - ' + cxGetResourceString(@sLangPop3ErrorReading));
  end;
end;
```

With advice from Remy Lebeau and searching the web I ended up with the code below. This does the trick for now, but I would like to improve it so that the memo on my form only shows a nice message that would be readable for everyone - but that may come later.

```
procedure TfrmJsMailCollect.lstMailsClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  MailBody: string;
  i: integer;
  ContentType: string;
begin
  if (lstMails.Items.Count = 0) or (lstMails.SelCount = 0) then
    Exit;
  try
    MailBody := '';
    mmoBody.Clear;
    lstMails.Selected.SubItems.Strings[0];
    lstMails.Selected.ImageIndex := 4;
    conPOP3.Retrieve(lstMails.Selected.Index + 1, IdMessage);

    ContentType := IdMessage.ContentType;
    case PosInStrArray(ContentType, ['multipart/mixed', 'multipart/alternative', 'text/html', 'text/plain'], False) of
      0:  begin   { multipart/mixed }
            for i := 0 To Pred(IdMessage.MessageParts.Count) do
              begin
                if TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[i]).Body.Text <> '' then
                  begin
                    MailBody := MailBody + TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[i]).Body.Text;
                    mmoBody.Lines.Add(MailBody);
                    MemoValidate;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
      1:  begin   { multipart/alternative }
            for i := 0 To Pred(IdMessage.MessageParts.Count) do
              begin
                if TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[i]).Body.Text <> '' then
                  begin
                    MailBody := MailBody + TIdText(IdMessage.MessageParts.Items[i]).Body.Text;
                    mmoBody.Lines.Add(MailBody);
                    MemoValidate;
                  end;
              end;
          end;
      2:  begin   { text/html }
            mmoBody.Lines := IdMessage.Body;
            MemoValidate;
          end;
      3:  begin   { text/plain }
            mmoBody.Lines := IdMessage.Body;
            MemoValidate;
          end;
    else
      // nothing supported to display...
    end;
    mmoBody.CaretPos.SetLocation(0, 0);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  except
    Logfile.Error('F_JsMailCollect.lstMailsClick - ' + cxGetResourceString(@sLangPop3ErrorReading));
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all email content is parsed into the `TIdMessage.MessageParts` collection.  MIME parts and attachments are, but other content gets parsed into the `TIdMessage.Body` instead, which you are completely ignoring.  You need to look at the `TIdMessage.ContentType` when deciding where to extract content from.  Attachments will always be in `TIdMessage.MessageParts`, but text may or may not be, depending on the `TIdMessage.ContentType`.

Comment: OK - I will try to have a look there to see if the missing part can be found.